# Como levantar texto de un archivo.txt y crear un objeto por cada linea del archivo e insertarlo en un List<Informe>

Tags: c#, poo, lista

Buenas lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiete. tengo un archivo.txt con lo siguiente

123;juan;Casemiro;Fisica;6.00;Martes, 14 de Agosto de 2020
132;Marcelo;Avila;Matematicas:8.00;Jueves, 16 de Agosto de 2020

Lo que quiero hacer es cargar cada valor en un objeto.

objeto1

legajo: 123
nombre:juan
apellido:casemiro
nombreMateria:fisica
Nota:.00
Fecha:Martes, 14 de Agosto de 2020

objeto2

legajo:132
nombre:marcelo
apellido:avila
nombreMateria:matematicas
Nota:8.00
Fecha:Jueves, 16 de Agosto de 2020

Luego cargar estos objetos en un List de tipo Informe, luego ordenarlo para poder pasar a realizar el corte de control.

```
public List<Informe> Lista()
    {
        string linea = "";
        string ruta = "C:/Ing. en sistemas 2/1° Año/2º Cuatrimestre/Programacion 1/2 Parcial/ArchivoSecuencial/ Archivo.txt";

        int legajo;
        string nombre, apellido, nombreMateria, fecha;
        float nota;

        List < Informe > lista = new List<Informe>();

        FileStream archivo = new FileStream(ruta, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader leer = new StreamReader(archivo);

        do
        {
            linea = leer.ReadLine();

            **string[] informe = new string[6];**

            informe = linea.Split(';');

            legajo = int.Parse(informe[0]);
            nombre = informe[1];
            apellido = informe[2];
            nombreMateria = informe[3];
            nota = float.Parse(informe[4]);
            fecha = informe[5];

            Informe infor = new Informe(legajo, nombre, apellido, nombreMateria, nota, fecha);

            lista.Add(infor);

        } while (linea != null);

        archivo.Close();

        return lista;
    }


    public List<Informe> OrdenarLista()
    {
        List<Informe> lista;

        lista = Lista();

        lista.Sort(
            delegate(Informe a, Informe b)
            {
                return a.legajo.CompareTo(b.legajo) & a.nombre.CompareTo(b.nombre);
            }
            );

        return lista;
    }
```

class Informe
{

```
    public int legajo;
    public string nombre;
    public string apellido;
    public string nombreMateria;
    public float nota;
    public string fecha;

    public Informe()
    {

    }


    public Informe(int legajo, string nombre, string apellido, string nombreMateria, float nota, string fecha)
    {
        this.legajo = legajo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.nombreMateria = nombreMateria;
        this.nota = nota;
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public void GenerarArchivoSecuencial()
    {
        int i = 1, j = 1;
        string ruta = "C:/Otro/Archivo.txt";
        
        FileStream archivo = new FileStream(ruta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter escribir = new StreamWriter(archivo);

        do
        {
            Alumnos alum = new Alumnos();

            escribir.Write(alum.CargarAlumnos(j));

            Notas not = new Notas();

            escribir.WriteLine(not.CargarNotas(j));
            j++;
            i++;

        } while (i <= 9);

        escribir.Close();
        archivo.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: el archivo tiene mas de dos lineas. El error es el siguiente: System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Esto sucede en el string[] informe, porque si esta referenciado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve replicando tu código en un proyecto en blanco, y funciona sin problemas la parte de lectura del txt [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu problema se debe entonces a la ruta de tu archivo
C:/Ing. en sistemas 2/1° Año/2º Cuatrimestre/Programacion 1/2 Parcial/ArchivoSecuencial/ Archivo.txt

Si te das cuenta tienes caracteres especiales y espacios, trata de moverlos a una carpeta como en mi caso:

```
C:/Otro/Leer.txt
```

Ya que al intentar hacer el `ReadLine();` no lo encuentra y te regresa null

[EDIT]

Adicional a lo anterior detecté que en tu archivo txt tienes : en lugar de ; en la segunda línea de Marcelo. Corregir esto también

Y agregar una condicionante a tu do while para validar que si la linea es `Null` se salga del ciclo antes de empezar las asignaciones:
[image: Agregar]

Comment: "C:/Otro/Archivo.txt" lo movi a esta carpeta pero sigo igual cuando le doy al boton para que me muestre la lista ordena en un listbok me sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Podrías agregar tu clase Informe para replicarlo?

Comment: añadi la clase esta crea el archivo obteniendo los datos que tengo en vectores de la clase alumno y notas

Comment: Listo, con la edición debería de funcionar

Comment: Gracias ahora si funciono

Comment: De nada, saludos!